# MYSQL TRIGGER If Statement Executing even if wrong value was passed

Tags: mysql, database-trigger

All the code here is correct except the if statement. For some reasons this if statement is not reading my var @qty_col_ctr's value. even if i pass 0, it still executes the update inside. is my syntax wrong?

btw this is an if statement inside a mysql trigger

```
if(@qty_col_ctr = 1)
then
        update sample_db_name.product_inventory_tb set qty = new.sku_stock 
        where product_id=@product_id and department_id=@department_id;

end if;
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't prefix the variable name with '@' inside trigger. Try this.

```
if(qty_col_ctr = 1)
```

Comment: i tried removing the @ but it gives me an error of unknown column qty_col_ctr in field list :(

Comment: Have you declared that field in your trigger before? Like DECLARE qty_col_ctr tinyint; SET qty_col_ctr =0;